# Integral of a 2-form over a cylinder

Tags: multivariable-calculus, manifolds, differential-topology, differential-forms

Let $S$ be the cylinder $0\leq z\leq1, x^2+y^2=1$ in $\mathbb{R^3}$ oriented with the outward normal. Let $D_0=${$(x,y,0)|x^2+y^2\leq1$} oriented with the downward normal and $D_1=${$(x,y,1)|x^2+y^2\leq1$} oriented with the upward normal. Let $\omega=xdx\wedge dy+ydx\wedge dz+zdx\wedge dy$. Is there any relationship between $\int_S \omega$, $\int_{D_0} \omega$ and $\int_{D_1} \omega$?

Comment: I think you have two typos in the post. Are you familiar with Stokes' theorem?

Comment: @AmitaiYuval what are the typos? Yes I am. But I am not seeing how I can apply it to this case

Comment: Except for the description of $D_0$ which you fixed already, the differential form $\omega$ seems to be written wrong. The three surfaces form the boundary of a domain on which it is fairly simple to integrate $d\omega$.

Comment: Yeah, I bet you mean $x\,dy\wedge dz + y\, dz\wedge dx + z\,dx\wedge dy$. And, yes, think about Stokes's Theorem. (Maybe a picture would help?)

Comment: @TedShifrin I can find $\int_S \omega$ by parametrizing the cylinder. $D_0$ and $D_1$ are disks not circles so can I count them as the boundary of this manifold?

Comment: No, these are *all* 2-dim. manifolds with boundary. What happens when you put them all together?

Comment: You get a closed cylinder?

Comment: Right, which is the boundary of ...

Comment: Solid cylider?..